# Firebase cloudstore get all collections in document in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am going to get all collections in a document
when I don't know the name of collections, how can I get all collections in a document

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('answers')
    .doc('vS55vOUPtNXaRY06IXIPq6V9ss73')
    .collection('uu')
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) {      

}).catchError((e){

});
```

Doument "vS55vOUPtNXaRY06IXIPq6V9ss73" has 2 collections , "uu" and "uy". This is dynamic.

[image]

Comment: There is no way to get a list of collections through the client-side SDKs of Firestore. You will have to already know the collection names in your code, or store them elsewhere (such as in an array field in the parent document).

Comment: Have a look at the following [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-list-all-subcollections-of-a-cloud-firestore-document-17f2bb80a166).

Answer (score 0):

`Firestore.instance.collection("answers").snapshots` this can be used to retrieve all the documents in firestore